# ef6 set only foreign key property of navigation property while saving

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

When I save entity which has navigation property which I use as foreign key:

```
this.HasRequired<Role>(c => c.Role).WithMany().Map(c => c.MapKey("role_id"));
```

I set only foreign key property of this navigation property (I get it from web page) thereby other properties of this navigation property are empty, but they have required restrictions:

```
this.Property(c => c.RoleName).IsRequired();
```

It's the reason why I get **"dbentityvalidationexception"** exception with error **"field is required"**.

Is it possible to solve this problem by somehow? 
Or I must get full entity for that navigation property from DB, set navigation property of entity which I save and then save my initial entity (It works now, but it doesn't look like good solution)?

Thanks in advance.

This is MS MVC action where I handle the model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddAsync(Staff staff)
    {
        await staffService.InsertAsync(staff);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and that part of view where I set the property:

```
    <dt>
        @Html.Label("Role")
    </dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(_=>_.Role.Id, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles, "Id", "RoleName"), "- Please select a Role -")
    </dd>
```

this is the type of model "Staff"

```
public class Staff
{
    public Staff()
    {
        Name = new Name();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Name Name { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you're setting the property?

Answer (score 0):

I have found more or less good solution for that problem.
I have set all navigation property for which I have only foreign key property as
EntityState.Unchanged.

Now I have this method for saving only specific entity (Staff)

```
    public virtual Staff InsertStaff(Staff entity)
    {
        context.Entry(entity.Role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        context.Entry(entity.Maneger).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        SetStaffNavigationPropertiesUnchanged(entity);
        return dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

and this for saving full graph (in base generic class):

```
    public virtual TEntity InsertGraph(TEntity entity)
    {
        return dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

using "EntityState.Unchanged" (I will show in simplest way) lets me saving Staff when Role has only foreign key property filled (Role has RoleName required property)

```
        using (ClinchContext context = new ClinchContext())
        {
            var role = new Role { Id = 1 };

            Staff staff = context.Staffs.Add(new Staff
            {
                Name = new Name { Firstname = "FN", Surname = "S", Patronymic = "P" },
                Email = "E",
                Login = "L",
                IsDeleted = false,
                Role = role,
                Maneger = null//nullable for now
            });

            context.Entry(staff.Role).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

If someone has more proper solution I would be happy to know, Thank you.